# Hide button when get intent from a specific class - Android

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-button

I want to hide a button when it get intent from a specific class.

**Is it possible?**

For instance, i have classes named A_activity.class, B_activity.class and C_activity.class . In C_activity.class , if it get intent from A_activity.class, the button is visible. But if it get from B_activity.class, the button is invisible.

This is my source code

```
Intent i=getIntent();

    buttonTTS = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonTTS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            speakOut();
        }
    });
```

What should i do with my code?

Comment: buttonTTs.setVisibility(View.GONE) or buttonTTs.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

Comment: put bool flag into intent which will start C_activity then in C_activity based on this flag set visibility of the button ... where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this. When you're creating the Intent from activity A you should add extra:

```
intent.putExtra("buttonVisible", true);
```

And from activity B

```
intent.putExtra("buttonVisible", true);
```

And in your activity C:

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("buttonVisible", false)){
    buttonTTS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
} else 
buttonTTS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

From A_Activity `putExtra("showButton", true)` and from B_Activity `putExtra("showButton", false)`

Now in C_Activity, getExtras and hide and show button.

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a **tag** with the intent and then check the tag with the class value then you can make hide or show the button.

```
putExtra("tag","A_activity");
```

Now in class C you can check it by taking it in string and compare it by value.

```
String tag = getIntent().getStringExtra("tag");

if(tag.equals("A_activity")){

button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

else{
     ....
    }
```